# Conflict with foreign key on table users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the users table, generated by laravel and a store table, I want all users to have a foreign key from the id store, but when I add the id it tells me that there has been an error with the foreign format ... With other tables if it works, it is only with the users that gives me conflict, I do not know if it could be because it is created before the table stores, but still I have changed the name to do the store migration before, but nothing , still the same. Thanks for the help!

```
>   [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
> error: 1005 Can't create table `Shop`.`#sql-17ec_5` (errno: 150
> "Foreign key constraint    is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table
> `users` add constraint `users_store_id_foreign` foreign key (`store_id
> `) references `store` (`id`))
> 
> 
> 
>   [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create
> table `shop`.`#sql-17ec_5` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint    is
> incorrectly formed")
```

Comment: Please provide the migration code and the error you received

Comment: First create both tables then try adding a new migration after them to add the foreign key constraints.

Comment: Show us your code.  Show us the error.  Please visit the help centre and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Done! that is the error, thanks for the anwers

Answer (score 0):

In case of small data:

Check if the foreign id you put in users table is already exists as id in store table or not.

In case of bulk data:

First remove the foreign key check.

Second Update all the users table with their Store Ids.

Third Run a Manual check by a select query to export a list of non existed Store ids of useres in the main table of stores.

```
Select user.ID, user.name, user.Store_ID from users 
Where Store_ID not IN (Select ID from Store)
```